# How much is one meter in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am currently working on a game in spriteKit and Swift 2 for IOS 8 and I needed some anti-gravity. when I looked up the linearGravityWithVector function on the apple documentation it said this, *"The direction and magnitude of the gravitational force. The values represent the acceleration of the field in **meters per second squared**. For example, to simulate earth’s gravity, specify (0, -9.8)"*. What do they define as a meter? is it an actual meter or do they scale it so there the height of the phone is "one meter".

Comment: Why don't you test it? Set up an object to fall under gravity and then in Update() print the time and the current position of the object. By using the formulas for acceleration, you should be able to work out how many CGPoints make a 'meter' in an SKScene. From stationary, an object will fall ½at² = 0.5 x 9.8 x 1² = 4.9m. But I suspect this will only be of academic use, and not something actually useful in a game.

Comment: Should point that that in the calculation above, it's 4.9m in the first second and after exactly 1 second, it's speed should be at = 9.8 x 1 = 9.8m/s

Comment: See the answer on a possible duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504964/how-to-get-scene-height-in-meters-swift/37523818#37523818