# How to get scene height in meters (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have my height as `self.frame.height` which returns 736 as expected for an iPhone 6s. How do I convert this value into meters to be consistent with the physicsWorld unit system??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about 135 points to a meter.

A physicsBody left to fall from stationary under gravity of 9.8m/s travelled 660 points in 1.00806862953687s (1.01s), with a velocity of 1342.8162841796875m/s (1342.82).

Doing the maths to 2 decimal places, we can use both the equations of distance travelled and speed to calculate the number of points per meter through 2 different calculations:

Using v=u+at (u=0, a=9.8, t=1.01s), we can calculate that after 1.01s, v is 1.01 * 9.8 = 9.90m/s. The physicsbody's velocity is 1342.85, Therefore 9.90m/s = 1342.82 points/s so 1m = 135.6 points.

Or, using s=ut+½at², to calculate the distance travelled after time t, we get s = 0.5x9.8x1.01 = 4.95m. Therefore 4.95m = 660point; 1m =  133.3 points.

If you do the maths with the full precision, you get a figure of 137 points.

Using the timings after approx 2 seconds gives a figure of 133.4 points/m from the acceleration formula and 133.7points/m from the distance formula

What is odd is that the SKPhysicsBody class reference described the velocity property as being in meters/second, but it definitely appears to be in points per second.

Comment: It would seem - insane - that velocity is given in anything other than velocity (ie, m/s).  Do you blokes know if that oddity is still the case???

Comment: Oops - never saw this comment until now. I don’t know, but might test it again. Remember though that points-per-second (p/s) is just as valid a velocity unit a meters/second.

Comment: right @steveives - it's surely a valid unit of measurement.  But every physics engine on Earth (including Box, on which the Apple one is a port) of course uses actual distances (meters or perhaps feet: FWIW I don't know any that use Imperial), not points!  Strange stuff!

Answer (score 1):

You know gravity is 9.8 m/s^2, so take an object, put it in the air, and measure the distance travelled after 1 second.  then you know that 
`X points/sec = 9.8 meters/1^2`
`X points/1 = 9.8 meters/1^2`
`X points = 9.8 meters/1`
`X points = 9.8 meters`
Final answer:
`X/9.8 points  = 1 meter`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520034-area) of the `area` property of the `SKPhysicsBody` class states that 1 meter in the Sprite Kit physics world corresponds to 150 points on screen.