# Velocity: Meters per second or pixels per second?

Tags: sprite-kit

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519635-velocity) states that a physics body's velocity is measured in meters per second.

Is this true? Is there a relationship between pixels and meters? If there is, what is it?

Or is this an error in the documentation and it's really pixels per second?

Comment: The [documentation on area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520034-area) says: "The value returned for the area is measured in meters: if you need to convert it into points — as used by SpriteKit — multiply the values by 150²." So you could probably figure it out from there.

Comment: thanks where did you get the number 150^2 from ?

Comment: From the above linked documentation on the `area` function. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520034-area

Comment: it isnt 150^2.  Area is 150^2 because it involves a length and width.  Velocity is a vector, so it is only 150

Comment: Isn’t it 1 point to a meter? This has had me scratching my head a while. If you remove all gravity and linear dampening from a node. Assign the node a velocity of dy10. With the game loop having deltaT of approx 0.016667 the object would move 0.16667 points. Which is 10 points per second. If Velocity in SKphysics world is Nm then that means 1Nm is the force needed to move 1 kg of mass through 1 point.

Comment: no, it is not 1point to a meter.  If it was, applyForce would not be bugged, forcing you to add 150 times the amount you would for applyImpulse

Comment: you are assuming your node is 1kg.  1 point is 0.00004444444552063942 kg.  you need 22500 points to make 1kg, so a 150x150 sprite..... 150 is the magic number apparently lol

Comment: ahhh butt this is it I missed this of off my last comment it was late!!! I set the mass to zero. This is what Xcode gave me back!!. What else I found interesting was if you use applyForce for say dy:100. You get 1.66667 points of movement per second or 0.02775 points per game loop with Dt at 0.016667. Which means (to my small brain) applyForce just applies a Velocity vector per minute instead of per second like with applyImpulse or just setting the velocity.

Comment: Apply force is bugged. If you do 150 it will get you the same result as apply impulse.  Apply impulse happens immediately, apply force happens during physics updates.  You are suppose to continuously apply force via a game loop, but you only apply impulse once.  This is the difference between pushing a car with your body (force) and slamming into it with another car (impulse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to anyone and myself

There is nothing to really define a pixel within apples SKSpriteKit, this is a misnomer in my question. A point on the other hand is well defined.

Everybody probably already knows this but if you attach a SKPhysicsBody to a Node and assign the following properties:

```
    seg.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    seg.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    seg.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    seg.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    seg.physicsBody?.mass = 0
    seg.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    seg.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
```

Then applying a velocity dy component of 200 results in the object moving at 200 points per second. This says to me that with all external forces remove Sprite kits physics world translates to 1m/s = 1point/s.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small program to try to work this out and got an answer of 135 points to the metre.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523818/1430420

Edit: Here is the program for anyone to check to see if my maths is off

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  gravityTest
//
//  Created by Steve Ives on 30/05/2016.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Steve Ives. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

//    var elapsedTime: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    var timeOfLastUpdate: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    var updateCount = 0
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

//        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-9.8, 0)

        let location = CGPoint(x: (scene?.frame.midX)!, y: (scene?.frame.midY)!)

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5

        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        sprite.position = location

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
                updateCount += 1
        if (currentTime - timeOfLastUpdate) < 1 {return}

//        if (timeOfLastUpdate - currentTime > 1.0) {
        print("\(updateCount) - Time : \(currentTime) \(currentTime-timeOfLastUpdate) Location is : \(sprite.position) Velocity is : \(sprite.physicsBody!.velocity)")
//        }

        timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your times here?  You are 1 frame off from your results being 150.  DId you save this program by chance?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon interesting... I should have; I’ll save if I can find it.

Comment: I posted my code as well,  seems we have a timing discrepency here between you and me.

Comment: You are using the next update cycle instead of capturing it during the cycle it moved, perhaps that is what is throwing off your numbers?

Comment: I’ll have a play - If Apple say it’s 150 then obviously that is the figure we should believe first. Need to get back into coding after changing jobs but I have my new (to me) Mac Pro 2013 to play with 

Comment: Thanks I'll try these myself early tomorrow and see what results I get back as well. I really need the physics system to tie in with my numbers

Comment: Hang on if I apply a force of 100.dy. No gravity or friction. Then in one second the object moves 100 points vertical . Apple documentation gives a physics bodies velocity as in meters per second. Thus 1 meter = 100 points.

Answer (score 1):

I used playground to calculate my distance.  I am getting around 150

We know distance is d = (gt^2)/2 where g is gravity and t is time.

d = (9.8m/t^2)(t^2)/2
d = (9.8m)/2
d = 4.9m

In 1 second, we would travel  4.9m

In our case, we travelled 765.9298706054688 points.

765.9298706054688/4.9 gets us around 156.312218491.

Ideally, we would have travelled 735 points,  not sure what in my code could cause a 30 point difference, I suspect it has to do with SKAction

```
//: A SpriteKit based Playground

import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var testNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    private var flag = false
    private var time : CGFloat = 0
    private var beginTest = false
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    }

    @objc static override var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        // SKNode conforms to NSSecureCoding, so any subclass going
        // through the decoding process must support secure coding
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    }



    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: testNode.size)
        physicsBody.angularDamping = 0
        physicsBody.linearDamping = 0
        physicsBody.friction = 0
        testNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
        let action = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 2)
        {
            node,elapsedTime in
            if elapsedTime >= 1 && !self.flag && self.time == 0{
                self.flag = true
                self.time = elapsedTime
            }
        }
        testNode.run(action)
        beginTest = true
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if beginTest{
            beginTest = false
            addChild(testNode)
        }
    }
    override func didFinishUpdate() {

    }


    override func didApplyConstraints() {
        if flag{
            let position = CGPoint(x:testNode.position.x,y:-testNode.position.y)

            print("Node traveled \(position.y) points over \(time) seconds with a velocity of \(testNode.physicsBody!.velocity)")

            let pointsPerMeter = -testNode.physicsBody!.velocity.dy/9.8
            print("Node traveled \(pointsPerMeter) points per meter over \(time) seconds with a velocity of \(testNode.physicsBody!.velocity)")
            flag = false
            testNode.removeFromParent()
            time = 0
        }
    }
}

// Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 640, height: 480))
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

> Node traveled 765.9298706054688 points over 1.0 seconds with a velocity of (0.0, -1494.4998779296875)
>   Node traveled 152.49998754384566 points per meter over 1.0 seconds with a velocity of (0.0, -1494.4998779296875)