# Swift SpriteKit velocity unit is point not meter?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Here is my testing code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 1000) // size height: 1000 unit: point
        let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 150)
        ball.fillColor = .red
        let phyBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 150)
        phyBody.linearDamping = 0
        ball.physicsBody = phyBody
        phyBody.affectedByGravity = false
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 0)
        phyBody.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 100) // velocity: 100, unit ? (point/s or meter/s) 
        addChild(ball)
    }
}
```

My result is that the ball move from bottom to top in 10 seconds. That means the velocity is measured in points, not in meter. Which conflict to the documents https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519635-velocity. Am I wrong?

Comment: Better to think of it in terms of the scene size.  If your scene is 1000 units high, then a velocity of 100 units will mean traversing the scene in 10 seconds.  However, the scene size and the screen size in points need not be related.

Comment: It is not conflict is only an abstraction of concepts, if you see SKPhysicsWorld properties and .gravity every one use meters, it's an abstraction only. For sure, for define it uses a standard core graphics object measured and defined as "points" . But I don't see the problem whit this.

Comment: Maetschi is exactly right. add a physics body, remove gravity, apply a velocity of 100dy to the physics body. as long as your game loop is running at 60fps the object will move vertically by 100 * 0.016667 (approx) points or 1.6667 points. points = meters .. I had a similar question a while back  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824964/velocity-meters-per-second-or-pixels-per-second/59149353#59149353

Comment: According to the `area` function in (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520034-area), meter = 150 points. That conflicts.